# ImportError: cannot import name 'generate_password_hash'

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

```
from flask import jsonify
from flask import flash, request
from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
```

Error Please help me to fix these issues I have tried with pip install Werkzeug But not working

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 6, in 
    from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
ImportError: cannot import name 'generate_password_hash'**

Answer (score 16):

You can try

```
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
```

or check the version of werkzeug installed in your system. Those functions are available for version 1.0.x

Answer (score 7):

Those functions were deprecated for a while and now they are moved to  `werkzeug.security`

```
DeprecationWarning: The import 'werkzeug.generate_password_hash' is deprecated and will be removed in Werkzeug 1.0. Use 'from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash' instead.
  from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
DeprecationWarning: The import 'werkzeug.check_password_hash' is deprecated and will be removed in Werkzeug 1.0. Use 'from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash' instead.
  from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
```